# How to make html5 canvas display crisp image based off chrome screencap

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, blurry

I am making a chrome extension that uses the chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab method to grab a screencap of the current tab and then displays that in a popup from the chrome extension. If I use the img tag and use the data coming from the chrome function, such as `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwME…UUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAf/2Q==`, the `<img>` displays pixel perfect, it is crisp and that's what I want. Problem is that I need to make it into a canvas, and when I do that, it becomes blurry.

[This is a screencap of the `<img>` that uses the link data provided by Google to be used as a comparison to the canvas which is below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVZWV.png)

[This is the blurry canvas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/745WU.png)

This is the code that I am using to try to do this, but I can't figure out how to make the canvas crisp like the image.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: "capture"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.imgSrc);
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var _canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    img.src = response.imgSrc;
    img.height = 436;
    img.width = 800;
    document.getElementById('main-canvas').appendChild(img);
    draw(response);
});

function draw(response) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    //Get a 2d context
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //use image to paint canvas
    var _image = new Image();
    _image.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(_image, 0, 0, 800, 436);
    }
    _image.src = response.imgSrc;

   document.getElementById('main-canvas').appendChild(canvas);
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can see is, you are taking a picture with the dimention from 436 X 800 and then drawing it into the size of Window Width/Height. Also you move the picture from 0.5px.

Comment: @ManuelChoucino I am new to this, so if I have things backwards, I will adjust, but what I am trying to do is take the full size screencap from chrome and condense it down to an 800 * 436 canvas, but I want to retain the crisp text that an image element of the same size would have, as the links show. I'm not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: There is an option in the canvasContext2D object called [imageSmoothingEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) set by default to true. This is still considered as experimental and you'll need vendor-prefixes : `ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;`. Also, it is not widely supported by all browser's version (IE9&10), so you may need to perform your own nearest-neighbor algo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used to fix my problem: [High Resolution Canvas from HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/)